# How to use group action to show that the group of orientation symmetries of a cube is isomorphic to S4?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I fail to see how considering the group of symmetries of a cube's action on the set of the 4 diagonals proves injectivity of the map $\phi$ from G to S4.

I think surjectivity follows from injectivity, but the latter seem to be the hard part, I solved this problem by considering all of the possible symmetries and shown that there are 24 of them, but was unable to prove injectivity, my professor claims that using group actions gives an easy argument for it.

edit: I don't see how this can be done without resorting to some form of geometric argument, my professor make it sound like group action is an alternative.

Comment: Note that any such orientation-preserving symmetry of the cube acts on a set with cardinality $4$, the set of long diagonals of the cube. This gives us the map $\phi$. We can explicitly display $24$ such symmetries, and thus injectivity = surjectivity. Now note none of your 24 symmetries fix all $4$ diagonals, except the identity (for example, a rotation of 90 degrees about two opposite face centers must map to a $4$-cycle-this eliminates 9 symmetries as elements of the kernel of $\phi$). It suffices to find 3 more non-elements of the kernel (why?).

Comment: But this is exactly my point, when you say "Note none of the 24 symmetries fix all 4 diagonals except the identity, that's a geometric argument that doesn't seem to be able to bypass. Group action just  formalize the idea that any symmetry must permutes the diagonals (or act on), doesn't seem like there is any significant advantage to be gained here by using group action, as in there is no "AHA!" tricks offered by group actions.

Also once I have accepted that none of the 23 non identity symmetries fix all diagonals, doesn't that imply kernel of $\phi$ is then trivial ->injective->surjective

Comment: Yes, there is an advantage to using group actions: it tells you what the isomorphism is. Just having two abstract groups alone doesn't mean you have or know how to find the right function between them. Of course you won't be able to bypass geometry to argue the kernel is trivial, and arguing the kernel is trivial implies injectivity is the only thing I can figure you (or your professor, according to you) could mean by "using group actions" to prove injectivity.

Comment: Anon:

That makes much more sense, So
Following David's comment, how does eliminating 9 elements in G being in the kernel and finding 3 more such element imply the kernel must be trivial?

For all I know kernel of $\phi$ can still be of order 2, 4 or 8.